# using auto mapper with lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am new to C# and I'm following a course in C# where we are using a package named auto mapper which takes two inputs the source and the target and the code is :

```
  var User_id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var notifications = _context.UserNotifications
                .Where(un => un.UserId == User_id)
                .Select(un => un.Notification)
                .Include(n => n.Gig.Artist)
                .ToList();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDto>(); 
            r   var User_id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var notifications = _context.UserNotifications
                .Where(un => un.UserId == User_id)
                .Select(un => un.Notification)
                .Include(n => n.Gig.Artist)
                .ToList();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDto>(); 
            return          
   notifications.Select(Mapper.Map<Notification,NotificationDto>);
```

my question is in the last line why we have not passed the notification object to the `Map` Method like that :

```
return notifications.Select(n =>
Mapper.Map<Notification,NotificationDto>(n));
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notifications.Select(Mapper.Map<Notification,NotificationDto>);`

is a short version of

`notifications.Select(n => Mapper.Map<Notification,NotificationDto>(n));`

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#method-group-conversions