# Mapping lambda expression with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I try to map a lambda expression with AutoMapper

```
var expressionMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Expression<Func<ClientDTO, bool>>, Expression<Func<Client, bool>>>())
                .CreateMapper();

//type of predicate is Expression<Func<ClientDTO, bool>>
var expressionMapped = expressionMapper.Map<Expression<Func<Client, bool>>>(predicate);
```

Gives the following error :

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Error mapping types.'

ClientDTO

```
    public class ClientDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Nom { get; set; }
        public String Prenom { get; set; }
    }
```

Client (EF Entity)

```
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Nom { get; set; }

        public String Prenom { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please check this following link [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511230/using-auto-mapper-with-lambda-expression)

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping#readme

Comment: Thank you @LucianBargaoanu. I've installed the nuget package 
AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping and added the correct configuration to the mapper. It works fine.